# PHP league/route post request object

Tags: php, post, request, response, router

I am using league/route to handle routing for my application.

I have a post route:

```
$router = new RouteCollection;
$router->post('/url', 'MyClass::myMethod');

...$dispatcher->dispatch(...)->send();
```

In my method:

```
class MyClass {
    public function myMethod(Request $request) {
        var_dump($request->request);
    }
}
```

Var dumping the passed request object is just a fresh instance of HttpFoundation\Request, and not the actual request that the application has processed, i.e, there is no post data. To get the post data, I need to do:

```
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
```

Within my method. This makes the passed request object to my method useless. How can I configure Route to pass the actual request so I can get my post data, without having to create my own request object?

Answer (score 3):

The `RouteCollection` object accepts a dependency of league/container, a dependency injection container. This is where the Request object is pulled from when invoking your controller.

By design the request object is not built for you in case you would like to do anything specific with it yourself, so for this reason, it needs to be defined within the container or will return you a blank request each time. It is planned for this to be remedied in version 2 of the router due in the not too distant future of me posting this.

So something like this is required.

```
<?php


$container = new League\Container\Container;

$container->add('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request', function () {
    return Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request::createFromGlobals();
});

$router = new League\Route\RouteCollection($container);
$router->post('/url', 'MyClass::myMethod');

// ...

$dispatcher->dispatch(/* ... */)->send();
```

Comment: Facing the same issue at the moment and the github gives a 404 on the skeleton app.

Comment: Hello Philipo, Philipp from *Suggested Edits Review* here. It seems like the example skeleton application that you linked was no longer available. Yet, you created the github repo https://github.com/philipobenito/skel.app a few days ago.
Since it is empty, i approved the removal of the link to the non existent repo, but maybe you want to add your repo again.